# jquery: how to determine if a style is set via css class or hardcoded by style attribute?

Tags: jquery, css

For example given two divs like this:

```css
.example{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" style="height:100px;width:200px;z-index:5;">Hardcoded</div>
<div id="second" class="example" >Css</div>
```

How can i detect by jquery/javascript if, for example, the height of the div is set by style attribute? Or how can i detect by jquery/javascript if the height is set but not by a css class?

It seems there is a bunch of misunderstand what i'm really asking, altough one answer was pretty close but deleted:
The question is not "which value is set for the height". or "does the div has a specific class set" 
Given a specific style property like 'height'. I want to know two things:

1. Is the height set in any non-browser-default way like by a css class or style? (i think i can get by myself)
2. If yes, is the height set by the style="...." attribute or by a class=""? Which class doesnt matter.

Comment: i guess by pressing `ctrl+u` and use the find `ctrl+f`.

Comment: You could check the developer tools

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: you can check if an element has a class with jQuerys `element.hasClass()`

Comment: @Anonymous: cause i want to modify specific style attributes and need to reset them to previous values later. Given a class i just need to remove my changes, given hardcoded i need to save the previous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery as follows

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if($('#first').attr("style").indexOf("height") != -1) {
        alert("height is hardcoded");
     }
    else {
        alert("height is not hardcoded");  
     }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: stupid me, attr('style') and indexOf is a nice solution - thanks!